# Vortex with particle system without tornado effect for snowstorm scene

Tags: particles, physics

I'm trying to make a snowstorm effect in Blender. I have a plane that is emitting plane particles (with a snowflake texture mapped to it). There is also a Empty with a Force physics enabled on it. The Empty is set to vortex.

However, when I bake bake the plane's physics, the particles either pull into the center far too much (like a tornado) or blow outwards. No matter how I adjust the settings, I can't make the particles swirl around a certain axis.

How can I accomplish this? And are there any alternatives to particle systems, vortexes, etc.?

Comment: I'd recommend using something else, maybe a *Force* field, and then animate it. Snowstorms are either very regular (use *Wind* and Brownian value) or very sporadic (use many animated force fields).

Comment: I did a very quick test now, and setting the vortex inflow to a negative value about twice the strength, and scaling the empty to about twice the size of the plane looks like a step in the right direction. Not a complete solution though, and I'm inclined to agree with @NoviceInDisguise's suggestion.

Comment: you can try using boids. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Boids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the snow be blown in one direction and the same time to show some whirl, you could add an additional wind force and animate the vortexes force.

It is easier to verify the effect when you don't bake, instead manipulate the settings while the simulation is running.

[image]